# mvc3 cookie value not setting in ViewData page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cookies, httpresponse

I have a textbox and a submit button were people put in there enter a 5 number pin and then it is to be safed inside a cookie for 4 months but its not working im getting nothing out of it.. what could be wrong.. this is my first time trying cookies

**Read View**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    //read cookie and send it to view model
    var mycookie = Request.Cookies["mypreference"];
    ViewData["prefvalue"] = mycookie.Value;
    return View();
}
```

**HttpPost**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection ss)
{
    // create cookie
    HttpCookie preference = new HttpCookie("mypreference");
    preference.Value = ss["preffer"];
    preference.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(120d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(preference);
    return View();
}
```

**The view**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("seotips", "home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextBox("preffer") 
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
@ViewData["prefvalue"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to try this

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   HttpCookie coo = new HttpCookie("name");


    coo["Country"] = "INDIA";


    ViewData["prefvalue"] = coo["Country"];
    return View();
}
```